# I'm running Flask and it says there's no such file or directory

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, windows-10, python-sockets

I'm using Ubuntu on Windows 10 and when I do "flask run" I get this error. I've searched google but it seems no one had this kind of problem. I do have **socket.py** file.

**(api) ➜  api flask run:**

```
* Serving Flask app "app.py"                                                                                            
* Environment: production                                                                                                 
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.                                                
* Debug mode: off
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/luke/miniconda3/envs/api/bin/flask", line 10, in 
> sys.exit(main())
> File
> "/home/luke/miniconda3/envs/api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py",
> line 967, in main                         cli.main(args=sys.argv[1:],
> prog_name="python -m flask" if as_module else None)
> File
> "/home/luke/miniconda3/envs/api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py",
> line 586, in main                         return super(FlaskGroup,
> self).main(*args, **kwargs)
> File
> "/home/luke/miniconda3/envs/api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py",
> line 782, in main                        rv = self.invoke(ctx)
> File
> "/home/luke/miniconda3/envs/api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py",
> line 1259, in invoke                     return
> _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))                                                               File
> "/home/luke/miniconda3/envs/api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py",
> line 1066, in invoke                     return
> ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
> File
> "/home/luke/miniconda3/envs/api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py",
> line 610, in invoke                      return callback(*args,
> **kwargs)                                                                                      File
> "/home/luke/miniconda3/envs/api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/decorators.py",
> line 73, in new_func               return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args,
> **kwargs)                                                                            File
> "/home/luke/miniconda3/envs/api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py",
> line 610, in invoke                      return callback(*args,
> **kwargs)                                                                                      File
> "/home/luke/miniconda3/envs/api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py",
> line 860, in run_command                  extra_files=extra_files,
> File
> "/home/luke/miniconda3/envs/api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py",
> line 1052, in run_simple           inner()
> File
> "/home/luke/miniconda3/envs/api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py",
> line 1005, in inner                fd=fd,
> File
> "/home/luke/miniconda3/envs/api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py",
> line 848, in make_server           host, port, app, request_handler,
> passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd
> File
> "/home/luke/miniconda3/envs/api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py",
> line 740, in **init**              HTTPServer.**init**(self,
> server_address, handler)
> File "/home/luke/miniconda3/envs/api/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py",
> line 449, in **init**                                self.socket_type)
> File "/home/luke/miniconda3/envs/api/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line
> 151, in **init**
> _socket.socket.**init**(self, family, type, proto, fileno)                                                          FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: try create a venv and then run

Comment: I uninstalled conda and used venv then it worked thanks.

Comment: you don't need to uninstall conda, you can install it and create virtual env using it , or using pipenv